# Where can I find the export_saved_model attribute in the tensorflow.keras.experimental model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have already run the model. Now the error comes while exporting the model after training.

Here is the code:

```
SHOE_SAVED_MODEL = "saved_models/shoe"
tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, SHOE_SAVED_MODEL)
shoe_model = tf.keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model(SHOE_SAVED_MODEL,
custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})
```

Error in the code:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-59c886611cb2> in <module>()
      1 SHOE_SAVED_MODEL = "saved_models/shoe"
----> 2 tf.keras.experimental.export_saved_model(model, SHOE_SAVED_MODEL)
      3 shoe_model = tf.keras.experimental.load_from_saved_model(SHOE_SAVED_MODEL,
      4 custom_objects={'KerasLayer':hub.KerasLayer})

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.experimental' has no attribute 'export_saved_model'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of now the `tensorflow.keras.experimental` does not work anymore. To save your model use the `model.save('path')` function

```
saved_model_path = "./my_model.h5". # or you can simply use 'my_mode.h5'
model.save(saved_model_path) #save your model 

# to reload your model 
model = keras.models.load_model(saved_model_path)
```